# before_add callback using nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Given the following:

`Foo has_many :bars, :through => :baz`

and

`Foo accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar`

I want to do a `find_or_create_by_name` when I add a new `:bar`, but I don't know where I can have some sort of `before_add` functionality.

The background of this question is `Bar validates_uniqueness_of :name`, which gives errors when I try to create a new `Foo` that is using an existing `Bar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I must be tired:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, :through => :baz, :before_add => :some_callback

  def some_callback(b)
    #whatnot
  end
end
```

But still, in the `some_callback` portion, what to do?  I've tried things like `b = Bar.find_or_create_by_name(b.name)` but that doesn't work either.